# Passing array to a function in Go

Tags: arrays, go

```
func printArray(my_arr []int){  // ERROR: cannot use arr (type [8]int) as type []int in argument to printArray
   fmt.Println(len(my_arr))
}
func main(){
    arr := [...]int{17,-22,15,20,33,25,22,19}
    printArray(arr)
}
```

As in C++ we pass the array in a function using pass by reference. can we do same in GoLang?

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals like the difference between arrays and slices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array elements are passed by values in Go, i.e. the target function gets a copy of the array elements passed. Moreover, `[]int` refers to a slice of `int` and *not* an array of elements. If you want the traditional C like behaviour, pass the array by its address as `printArray(&arr)` and receive it as `array *[8]int`.

But even this style isn't idiomatic Go. Use slices instead.

```golang
func printArray(arr []int){   
   fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(arr))
}

func main(){
    arr := []int{17,-22,15,20,33,25,22,19}
    printArray(arr)
}
```

A slice is internally just a pointer to the backing array, so even when its passed by value, any changes to the slice on the receiving function modifies the original backing array and therefore the slice also.

Comment: So its better to use slice?

Comment: @ujjwal_bansal: Yes take the tour of Go - https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6 and understand more on the native types

Answer (score 3):

your `printArray(my_arr []int)` function's parameter expecting a slice, not an array.
In Go, from syntax `[...]{1,2,3}` creating an array with number of elements in the brackets.

NOTE: *If you have not any use case specially with an array, please use @inian's answer.*

So in this case, there is two ways to do this.

**1st way**

- send slice to print from the array

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printArray(my_arr []int) {
    fmt.Println(len(my_arr))
}

func main() {
    arr := [...]int{17, -22, 15, 20, 33, 25, 22, 19}
    printArray(arr[:])
}
```

**2nd way**

- accept array in `printArray` function.
- but this has some limitation, it will accept arrays with the one length. In this case it is 8.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printArray(my_arr [8]int) {
    fmt.Println(len(my_arr))
}

func main() {
    arr := [...]int{17, -22, 15, 20, 33, 25, 22, 19}
    printArray(arr)
}
```